# Esri storymap app deploy without AGOL login

Tags: arcgis-online, story-map

I was wondering if anyone has tried to modify the source code of any downloadable esri storymap templates so that it doesn't require AGOL login?

After reading this blog post:
http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/08/01/new-developer-subscriptions-for-arcgis-online/

"ArcGIS now supports OAuth so developers can build applications for organizations using ArcGIS Online. Developers can also expose ArcGIS Online functionality to users without ArcGIS logins and build consumer facing or B2B applications for wider audiences. Just create an app, register it, and it is assigned an App ID and App Secret."

it seems that it might be feasible, and I can generate the necessary IDs, but I am not sure how to modify the code to consume these IDs. Can anyone provide some guidance?

Ideally I would like to host the app on my server (with a proxy setting) and make it available to users with no AGOL subscription. Might be useful to mention that there will be no basemaps or feature layers in my app, just images and text.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If you share it publicly it should allow for anyone to see the story map, check to see that you don't have it shared to only yourself, or to a certain organization or group. That could be restricting the access to the story map.